# Having issue with creating a script

Tags: scripts, sudo

Trying to create a simple script but I'm not having any luck.
I created a file with nano, saved it. 
Then:

```
sudo chmod +x filename
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to restart networking after failed suspend

sudo service network-manager stop
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo service network-manager start
```

But when I test it, it says: `command not found`.

Comment: The `command not found` indicates that it cannot find the script (correct ? ). Are you in the same directory (where script is) ? If yes, try `./filename` , if not then give the full path where the script is. e.g `/home/$USER/bin/filename`

Comment: How do you test it?

Answer (score 0):

This is happen when you don't give the correct path for the script. You should use:

```
cd /path/to/script/
./filename
```

or only:

```
/path/to/script/filename
```

See also: [What is a full path name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/337443/147044)