# Whenever I try to execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m` it shows an error

Tags: command-line

It then ends up showing this:

```
Password: 
dd: /path/to/ubuntu.img: No such file or directory
```

Yet, I named my file ubuntu.img
It is already a dmg

The full name of the dmg on my desktop is "ubuntu.img.dmg"

Comment: paste here the whole path

Comment: Shreyass-MacBook-Air:Desktop Shreyas$ sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
Password:
dd: /path/to/ubuntu.img: No such file or directory

Comment: If you file is named `ubuntu.img.dmg`, why are you telling `dd` to pick `ubuntu.img`?

Comment: you have to put the whole file name: `ubuntu.img.dmg`

Answer (score 1):

You make (minimum) three mistakes:

1. This part from your command `/path/to` must be changed with ...[full path name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337443/what-is-a-full-path-name/337475#337475) for that file. You said that the file is on your desktop. If so, then you should change `/path/to` with `~/Desktop`.
2. You said the full name of the dmg is `ubuntu.img.dmg`. So, then you should use this name, not `ubuntu.img`.
3. I think that this part is wrong, also: `of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m`. See [`man dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) to understand why.

As a suggestion: before to copy a command and past it in terminal, you should think a little what exactly does that command. Sometimes can be dangerous!