# Change program call directory

Tags: 12.04, command-line, directory

I have to versions of a software (Tecplot). When I write "tec360" in the terminal it brings me the old version. How can I change the program call directory so that it will bring me the new version?

Comment: How did you install the old version? How did you install the new version?

Comment: @minerz029: Old version is installed to "/opt". The new version is installed to home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the new version you have installed to your `/opt` directory and replace the old one with the new one. Then have a system restart.

something like

```
sudo mv ~/tecplot /opt/
```

If you are not root , then do as follows in your terminal

```
gedit .bashrc
```

write a line at the end of the opened text file as

```
alias tec360="~/tp/bin/tec360"
```

Then save and close the text file.

Then in the terminal write as

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

now try again by calling your program.

Comment: But I am not super user. Thats why I installed it to home directory.

Comment: what is the executable path of your new tecplo

Comment: ~/tp/bin/tec360

Comment: In that file I saw the path of the old version. I just replaced it with the new version and it opened new version closing and opening terminal. So what is the difference between this way and that alias thing?

Comment: 1. previously your program was called with the old path and now you have changed the path to new program path where you have the new one installed.   2. alias will call the long executables with custom names set by user. http://www.linfo.org/alias.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep both versions and start the version which is installed in your home directory when you type `tec360`, then add the [full path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337443/what-is-a-full-path-name/337475#337475) of `tec360` to your PATH. For example, if the path of `tec360` is `~/tp/bin`, then add:

```
export PATH=$HOME/tp/bin:$PATH
```

See also:

- [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: typed that line, gave no error but did not work

Comment: @Shibli I said for example. But the path of `tec360` (I found out meanwhile) is `~/tp/bin`, so use `export PATH=$HOME/tp/bin:$PATH`