# Why doesn’t `mv file /dir` move the file to a subdirectory of the current working directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, paths, mv

I was in my `/etc` directory and typed the command

```
me@mylaptop:/etc$ sudo mv MyFile.conf /openvpn
```

I thought that would move the file into the directory `openvpn` which is a subdirectory of the `/etc` directory.  However, that doesn't seem to be what happened.  All that I can confirm is that the command got executed.

Answer (score 51):

Provided a directory with this name doesn’t exist, you renamed the file to `openvpn` located in your root directory `/`. To revert this, run:

```
sudo mv /openvpn /etc/MyFile.conf
```

If the directory did exist you moved the file inside it, then the reversion is:

```
sudo mv /openvpn/MyFile.conf /etc/
```

To move it to an existing subdirectory of the current directory you can run any one of these – those use *relative* paths:

```
mv MyFile.conf openvpn
mv MyFile.conf openvpn/
mv MyFile.conf ./openvpn
mv MyFile.conf ./openvpn/
```

`.` is a link to the current directory, so `./` at the beginning of a path means “in this directory”. The slash at the end means that `openvpn` is a directory and you want to move the file inside it. If you don’t provide it, the file will be *moved* into it if a directory with this name exists, else the file will be *renamed* to `openvpn`. With a `/` at the end, `mv` will warn you if the directory is missing and *not* rename, so that’s the secure way if you don’t want to rename.

If your path begins with `/` on the other hand it’s an *absolute* path regardless of the current working directory, it’s always relative to the root directory `/`. Using absolute paths for both file and destination your command would look like this:

```
mv /etc/MyFile.conf /etc/openvpn
mv /etc/MyFile.conf /etc/openvpn/
```

#### Further reading

- [What is a full path name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/337443/507051)
- [Absolute / canonical / relative paths on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398415/246819)

Comment: If you don't know whether or not the directory existed, try the `sudo mv /openvpn/MyFile.conf /etc/` command first. In the likely scenario the directory didn't exist, it'll just give you an error (probably "Not a directory") and not touch the filesystem. Then, you can just do `sudo mv /openvpn /etc/MyFile.conf`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use

```
me@mylaptop:/etc$ sudo mv MyFile.conf openvpn/
```

to move the `MyFile.conf` file into the `openvpn` sub-directory of `/etc/`.

On the other hand

```
me@mylaptop:/etc$ sudo mv MyFile.conf /openvpn
```

would move the file to the `/` directory as `openvpn` (i.e. rename as `openvpn`) instead (assuming `/openvpn` directory doesn't exist).

Comment: Also, the slash at the end of the first command is optional. But I guess it's a good habit to get into, as it'll make the command fail if it isn't a directory, rather than creating a confusing situation like OP described (or worse, overwriting an important file.)

Answer (score 4):

When you move a file, you tell the OS the directory into which you want to put it, or the new path you want to give it.

You told the OS "/openvpn". So it's going to do exactly that - check if /openvpn exists *(meaning an object called "openvpn" located in the root directory)*  and is a directory, and if so move your file into it, or else if /openvpn is a file or doesn't exist, rename and move your file so it's now accessible as /openvpn.

What you wanted it to do was move it to **within a directory "openvpn", which is to be found in your current directory**, not one that's in the file system root directory (which is what the leading "/" signifies).  So you had to point to **that** dir in the move command, not to absolute path "/openvpn". Any of these will work:

- `mv MyFile.conf openvpn` - look in my current dir for this "openvpn"
- `mv MyFile.conf /etc/openvpn` - look for absolute path /etc/openvpn
- `mv MyFile.conf openvpn/` - look in my current dir, for a dir called openvpn
- `mv MyFile.conf ./openvpn` - makes the "current dir" even more obvious

*Short version - you probably used "/" to mean "my current directory", therefore "/openvpn" to mean "openvpn which is in my current directory". But a leading "/" only ever means "the root directory", so "/openvpn" meant "openvpn in the root directory". What you needed was simply to use "openvpn" or "openvpn/", meaning "openvpn in my **current directory**".*

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted; it's correct and I actually think it's the clearest!

Answer (score 1):

**Any path that starts with `/` is an absolute path, not relative.**

If all paths were always relative to the current directory, how would you `cd /etc` in the first place?  You'd have to `cd ../../../../../etc` and hope that was enough levels of `..`, or just keep doing `cd ..` until you got to the root directory.

Or you'd need some other syntax to express absolute paths.  But Unix decided on `/` meaning absolute, anything else being relative to the process's current working directory.  So `mv MyFile.txt openvpn` would work.

---

And no, it wouldn't work well to infer absolute vs. relative from files existing or not.  We wouldn't want `mkdir` system calls to treat paths differently from `chdir` or `rename` system calls, and making the `mv` program do it just leaves room for inconsistency between `mv` and some other program that takes an output filename.

`mv` is already special because when the `rename()` destination is a directory, it appends the source filename to that destination directory and tries again.  But notice that one simple implementation strategy relies of the first `rename()` system call failing with `EEXIST` or `EISDIR`.  So we have to know whether a path is relative or absolute before checking the filesystem.

(Early Unix ran on slow computers, where extra checks if a directory existed could mean extra I/O if it wasn't cached, or more pressure on directory caching.  But I think sanity / correctness arguments are sufficient to explain why your first guess wasn't a plausible way for the system to work, without resorting to historical efficiency arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the other answers :

```
mv file.txt /location
```

is the same as, for Windows

```
mv file.txt c:\location
```

The **filesystem** in linux is thought in accordance to the **filesystem hierarchy standard**, or [FHS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for short. it helps you knowing where should a file be placed depending on its nature and content.

The first folder (equivalent to `c:` in Windows) is `/`.