# Cat command with variable in file name not working

Tags: cat

I want to cat or read the contents of file giving absolute path that contains a variable but its not working..

None of the below commands are working.
(`$line` here is the name of file)

```
content=`(cat /tmp/cygwin/cygwin/home/67642360/1.0.94/db/src/sql/oracle/updates/${line})`

cat '/tmp/cygwin/cygwin/home/67642360/1.0.94/db/src/sql/oracle/updates/'${line}
```

Comment: *"None of the below commands are working."* I recommend you **[edit]** this question with details about what *does* happen when you run those commands, including complete exact output. If that doesn't show the actual name of at least one one of the files for which it fails, please include that, too.

Comment: An example of what `$line` contains would be helpful. Maybe it already contains the directory name? Maybe it contains spaces? We simply do not know enough to help.

Comment: Close voters. Crafting answer.

Comment: You should say what shell/environment you're using. Also, whether you're running this at the command line or via a script? Might be worth giving the whole script, eg on pastebin.com. Also, if you haven't heard of shellcheck I recommend it for debugging shell scripts (eg it will tell you to use $() instead of `` [backticks]).

Answer (score 1):

If as you say $line contains the name of the file you wish to output , you can simply `cat` (or `more` or `less`) the variable. as in `cat $line`

A safer method that would work even if the filename includes spaces would be  `cat "$line"`

You should insure that you know the difference between [full and relative paths](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337443/what-is-a-full-path-name) as you aren't likely to get the results you want if you confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignation from cat:

```
content=$(cat /tmp/cygwin/cygwin/home/67642360/1.0.94/db/src/sql/oracle/updates/${line})
# Or
content=`cat /tmp/cygwin/cygwin/home/67642360/1.0.94/db/src/sql/oracle/updates/${line}`
```

cat a file from variable:

```
cat /tmp/cygwin/cygwin/home/67642360/1.0.94/db/src/sql/oracle/updates/${line}
# OR
cat "/tmp/cygwin/cygwin/home/67642360/1.0.94/db/src/sql/oracle/updates/${line}"
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `${line}`?

Can you try `echo ${line}`?

What shell are you using? You can set `line` to be a valid file name. I'm using bash in this example.

```
foo$ echo ${line}

foo$ echo "Hello World" > /tmp/foo.txt 
foo$ export line=foo.txt
foo$ echo ${line}
foo.txt
foo$ cat /tmp/${line}
Hello World
foo$
```